# The flot graph won't update after re-draw

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I created an array that contains all of the flot objects on the screen. Using the selection plugin, I am implementing a zoom feature.

Unfortunately, the code below does not work as expected. I can confirm with `console.log` that the options change. The `clearSelection()` also works but the graph never redraws.

Also, I don't think it matters but I'm using a time-based x-axis.

```
$(".flot").bind("plotselected", function (event, ranges) {

    var plot = flots['#'+event.target.id];

    plot.getOptions().xaxis.min = ranges.xaxis.from;
    plot.getOptions().xaxis.max = ranges.xaxis.to;


    plot.setupGrid();
    plot.clearSelection();
    plot.draw();

});
```

Comment: That code should work. Can you build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  For some reason I had to change the axes min and max using the xaxes[0].min and yaxes[0].min.

```
$(".flot").bind("plotselected", function (event, ranges) {

    var plot = flots['#'+event.target.id];

    plot.getOptions().xaxes[0].min = ranges.xaxis.from;
    plot.getOptions().xaxes[0].max = ranges.xaxis.to;

    plot.setupGrid();
    plot.clearSelection();
    plot.draw();

});
```